# 1a) Find $\sum_{k=0}^n (k^3 - (k-1)^3). $ 3 part question to proofs of sums.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

1a) Find a simple expression for the following sum: $$\sum_{k=1}^n (a_k - a_{k-1}) $$

1b) Find $$\sum_{k=1}^n (k^3 - (k-1)^3). $$

1c) Show that $$\sum_{k=1}^n k^2 = \frac{n(n + 1)(2n+1)}{6}$$
WITHOUT using induction method but by using the definition formula: $$\sum_{k=1}^n k= \frac{n(n + 1)}{2}$$

Any guidance would be great with any of these questions if you have time. No similar examples of these questions were in the textbook so I needed clarification on how to solve these type of questions. Thank you very much.

Comment: Are you familiar with telescoping sums? If you write each term in part a explicitly, a lot of terms will cancel.

Comment: we didn't cover telescoping sums but how would it work in these questions exactly?

Comment: The answer below shows exactly how this would work for part a and b (for $a_k=k^3$). For part c, write $(k-1)^3=k^3-3k^2+3k-1$, and use the linearity of the sum and the result you have in part b.

Answer (score 2):

Hint for (a) and (b): try writing out the sum without sigma notation.
$$\sum_{k=1}^n(a_k-a_{k-1})=\sum_{k=1}^n(-a_{k-1}+a_k)=-a_0+\color{blue}{a_1-a_1}+\color{red}{a_2-a_2}+\dots+\color{green}{a_{n-1}-a_{n-1}}+a_n={}?$$